# Ruby - how to use array with Date.strptime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I try to convert single String to date it works.

```
    require 'date'

    a=String.new
    a='20171023'
    puts b=Date.strptime(a,'%Y%m%d')
    puts b.yday()
```

How can I make it work with an array? I tried this way.

```
    require 'date'

    a=[20160106, 20132018, 20011221]
    b=a.each{|a| Date.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d').yday()}
    puts b
```

Comment: You should be using an Array of Strings, not Integers

Comment: What date would `20132018` parse to?

Comment: tried with a.map{|a| a.to_s} but it doesn't help

Comment: sorry 20132018 is just a example, can be any date

Comment: you tried same variable `a` withing block, try different one @lezi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a string, instead an integer as you're doing now:

```
a = ['20160106', '20130218', '20011221']
```

If you want to store the result of each operation in `b`, then you can use map instead each:

```
b = a.map { |date| Date.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d') }
```

Your second date is invalid, I guess is `20130218`.

```
require 'date'

a = %w[20160106 20130218 20011221]
b = a.map { |date| Date.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d').yday }
p b # [6, 49, 355]
```

`%w[ ... ]` is an array of strings, where you avoid using quotes and commas.

When you don't need to pass arguments to a method call, you can avoid parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

a = [20160106, 20131018, 20011221]
a.map { |n| (Date.parse n.to_s).yday }
```

NB the array is different from the OP's, I assume he made a typo of some sort as the second number-date was invalid.